Aligin verticies between start and end vertices?
Just wondering how I align vertices between the active and last point in a chain? Is there a way other than scaling to an axis? for example if the surface has angled flow and I want to align/disribute vertices but on an angle between the first and actie selected points?
Thanks for any feedback

Have you tried right click > LoopTools > Gstretch (you need to activate the LoopTools addon), or right click > Set Linear?

It looks as though, here, you might be looking for good flow in hard-surface curvatures, not straightening in all dimensions? Maybe it would be worth checking out Ian McGlasham's excellent tutorial on the full use of Loop Tools > Curve, here. The operator also has a 'Linear' setting.. not covered, there, but you'll see.

I managed to find a work around as Loop tools modes all gave results I didn't want. Basicllally I wanted to pick first and last point and arrange the points in one true view axis. In this case X. I scaled to active in X, then used shear to get the angle..
